Combining a DNA and ctma molecule in Amber MD
I am new to Computational Chemistry. I am working on a project that requires that I attach a bunch of ctma molecules to a dna molecule in Amber xleap. Is there a command in Amber xleap that can help with that work? Thank you
I tried combining the two molecules but Amber places them randomly. But if there's a command I could use to attach the CTMA to specific positions on the DNA it will be great.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
